# WINDOWS API: GetCurrentThread(); in C

Tags: windows, operating-system

I just started my college "adventures", and one of them is subject called operating systems. I must admit that the subject is the most boring ever. Last week, we got our first homework, and i do not know what to do as this is the first time ever i come up with Windows API functions or this topic in general. The task is very simple, we need to write very basic code in C that shows how does GetCurrentThread() work!!!???? I tried looking for solution online, but I could not find anything and our professor is not doing anything to help us. I found the use of functions like GetCurrentThreadID() but that is not what i need. Can somebody write simple program ( 20-30 lines of code ) which contains the use of this function (in C)?

Comment: `HANDLE WINAPI GetCurrentThread()
{
 return (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -2;
}`

Comment: Do you want to know how to implement it (which @RbMm shows above) or an example of how to use it?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating systems courses tend to suck because they take the simplest of concepts and try to make them convoluted.

Documentation for the GetCurrentThread () function is

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthread

What it does not explain is that the return value for the function is a "handle." Windoze uses handles somewhat as pointers to objects but where you cannot access the object directly.

So you call GetCurrent() thread and it returns a "Handle to the Thread." That handle can then be used to do things with the thread.

Here are the things you can do:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-and-thread-functions

Some of these function pages have short examples.

So you could do:

```
print ("Thread ID: %d\n", GetThreadID (GetCurrentThread())) ;
```

and have the ID of the current thread.